# bootstrap form-group vs row CSS which one prefer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used **row** and now using **form-group** CSS.
I am confused between these 2, which one should I prefer if I want to build form controls. Seems like both  do same job.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I usually follow this pattern:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Note the `col-md-6` and `col-md-5` are examples and you can use any `col-md-x` class with unlimited number. just sum MUST be 12.

Comment: When the .form-group is inside a .form-horizontal, you don't need .row. This point is mentioned at: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal.  The exact lines are: Doing so changes .form-groups to behave as grid rows, so no need for .row

Comment: according https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#form-groups ,  you can use form-group to give standard for each row inside an html form , inside form-group you can use row or form-row class to organize columns inside a row

Comment: Are you sure you need to have a row inside Form-group. I believe you have directly specify col-md-x inside form-group same as row

Comment: `class="form-horizontal"` is deprecated in bootstrap 4. We can use form-group and row together in the same div: `<div class="form-group row">`, according to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#horizontal-form

Answer (score 6):

The direct answer to your question is in the documentation:

> ".form-row" is a variation of our standard grid class ".row" which overrides the
>   default column gutters for tighter and more compact layouts

See here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-grid

Answer (score 2):

This is for Bootstrap.

form-group per set of controls on a form. If your row has multiple cols, and each col has a label and an input text, put a form-group around each label and input control, such as:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Client Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="clientName" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Client Email: </label>
            <input type="text" name="clientEmail />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

... etc.
```